# Placefolder or value for react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I use  `<input type="text">`  in React.

Now I use this `<input type="text" placefolder="default">`

I can see the default value in thin letters.

When using,

`<input type="text" value="default">`

There comes the letter `default` in the box, however, it can't be edited like readonly.

Why this happen? how can I make it editable with value?

Comment: Are you asking how to automatically remove/select the default value when the input is focused so it can be overwritten?

Comment: You need to use `defaultValue` instead of `value`. What you see in your input box won't change unless `value` changes, And you're not changing it anywhere. If you want a `placeholder` which also is a default value, try using `defaultValue`.

Comment: ^ https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#default-values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to show a placeholder (which isn't a value [default or otherwise], it's just a hint), the prop is `placeholder`, not `placefolder`.

If you want to set a default value, that's the `defaultValue` prop, not `value`. (See the [instance properties of `HTMLInputElement` instances](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#instance_properties); remember, JSX is not HTML. Props are instance properties of objects, not attributes in HTML text.)

But this answer is primarily to explain this:

> When using,
>
> ```html
> <input type="text" value="default">
> ```
>
> There comes the letter default in the box, however, it can't be edited like readonly.

That's because when you use the `value` property on an `input` component in React, you're saying what its **actual value should be**. Unless you make that a state variable (or similar) and pair it with an `onChange` handler that updates the state variable (a [*controlled component*](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)), you'll never be able to change the value. If you want an [*uncontrolled component*](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html), don't specify `value` at all (and read the value directly, for instance via a ref). More in the documentation: [Controlled vs. Uncontrolled Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/glossary.html#controlled-vs-uncontrolled-components).